First Come First Serve Scheduling Algorithm Simulation
We were tasked to make a system to create a first come first serve scheduling algorithm. We were allowed to use any language and we chose JS, HTML, CSS. The code runs but the dots do not connect. Here's the Output:
Here's the code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>FCFS Scheduling Algorithm</title>
<style>
  body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .container {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 50px auto;
  }
  canvas {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <h1>FCFS Scheduling Algorithm</h1>
  <p>Enter process burst times separated by commas:</p>
  <input type="text" id="burstTimesInput" placeholder="e.g., 5,3,2,4">
  <button onclick="plotGraph()">Plot Graph</button>
  <canvas id="graphCanvas" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</div>
<script>
  function plotGraph() {
    const burstTimesInput = document.getElementById('burstTimesInput').value;
    const burstTimes = burstTimesInput.split(',').map(Number);

    if (!burstTimes.every(time => Number.isInteger(time) && time > 0)) {
      alert("Please enter positive integers only.");
      return;
    }

    const canvas = document.getElementById('graphCanvas');
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    
    const graphHeight = canvas.height - 50;
    const graphWidth = burstTimes.length * 50;
    const lineSpacing = 50;

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    let startX = 50;
    let prevX = startX;
    let prevY = graphHeight;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(prevX, prevY);

    for (let i = 0; i < burstTimes.length; i++) {
      const nextX = startX + lineSpacing;
      const nextY = graphHeight - burstTimes[i] * 10;
      
      // Draw point
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(nextX, nextY, 3, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
      ctx.fill();
      
      // Connect the dots with a line
      ctx.lineTo(nextX, nextY);
      
      prevX = nextX;
      prevY = nextY;
      startX += lineSpacing;
    }

    ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.stroke();

    // Draw timeline
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(30, graphHeight + 10);
    ctx.lineTo(graphWidth + 20, graphHeight + 10);
    ctx.stroke();

    // Draw timeline arrows
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(30, graphHeight + 5);
    ctx.lineTo(40, graphHeight + 10);
    ctx.lineTo(30, graphHeight + 15);
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(graphWidth + 20, graphHeight + 5);
    ctx.lineTo(graphWidth + 10, graphHeight + 10);
    ctx.lineTo(graphWidth + 20, graphHeight + 15);
    ctx.fill();
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>

To connect the dots with a line, and also to improve the code and output.

Your sequencing for drawing the lines was just a little off. You had all the correct settings and function calls, just not quite in the right places.
You need .strokeStyle and .lineWidth set above the loop. You need .beginPath() and .moveTo() just before the .lineTo() and .stroke() just after it. Get rid of the .stroke() that is just after the loop.
See the NOTE comments in the code snippet. You can also run the code snippet to see the changes working.


function plotGraph() {
    const burstTimesInput = document.getElementById('burstTimesInput').value;
    const burstTimes = burstTimesInput.split(',').map(Number);

    if (!burstTimes.every(time => Number.isInteger(time) && time > 0)) {
      alert("Please enter positive integers only.");
      return;
    }

    const canvas = document.getElementById('graphCanvas');
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    
    const graphHeight = canvas.height - 50;
    const graphWidth = burstTimes.length * 50;
    const lineSpacing = 50;

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    let startX = 50;
    let prevX = startX;
    let prevY = graphHeight;
    
    // NOTE Need these for drawing the line
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    
    // NOTE These two calls are not neccessary
    //ctx.beginPath();
    //ctx.moveTo(prevX, prevY);

    for (let i = 0; i < burstTimes.length; i++) {
      const nextX = startX + lineSpacing;
      const nextY = graphHeight - burstTimes[i] * 10;
      
      // Draw point
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(nextX, nextY, 3, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
      ctx.fill();
      
      // Connect the dots with a line
      // NOTE Add .beginPath(), .moveTo(), and stroke()
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
      ctx.lineTo(nextX, nextY);
      ctx.stroke();
      
      prevX = nextX;
      prevY = nextY;
      startX += lineSpacing;
    }

    // NOTE Move style and width above the loop
    //ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
    //ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    //ctx.stroke();

    // Draw timeline
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(30, graphHeight + 10);
    ctx.lineTo(graphWidth + 20, graphHeight + 10);
    ctx.stroke();

    // Draw timeline arrows
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(30, graphHeight + 5);
    ctx.lineTo(40, graphHeight + 10);
    ctx.lineTo(30, graphHeight + 15);
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(graphWidth + 20, graphHeight + 5);
    ctx.lineTo(graphWidth + 10, graphHeight + 10);
    ctx.lineTo(graphWidth + 20, graphHeight + 15);
    ctx.fill();
  }
body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .container {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 50px auto;
  }
  canvas {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
  }
<div class="container">
  <h1>FCFS Scheduling Algorithm</h1>
  <p>Enter process burst times separated by commas:</p>
  <input type="text" id="burstTimesInput" placeholder="e.g., 5,3,2,4">
  <button onclick="plotGraph()">Plot Graph</button>
  <canvas id="graphCanvas" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</div>



